# Has there been any development regarding lifelike helical dust structures? (Tsytovich et. al. 2007)

Tags: plasma-physics, biophysics, biology

[Tsytovich et. al. 2007](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230913206_From_plasma_crystals_and_helical_structures_towards_inorganic_living_matter) proposed that some interaction of dust and plasma might produce inorganic lifelike structures. Has there been any development regarding such theories?

Comment: Permalink: https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/9/8/263

Comment: The article is difficult to grasp. Researchgate has a somewhat bad reputation. My main objection is that the temperature of the plasma (in space) is too high. It would destroy the alleged structures.